# dt-bindings/clock/bcm2835.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-kernel

I trying to build the android kernel for Raspberry Pi 2 from https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi2, but I am facing the following build error when building dtbs:

```
$ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make dtbs

  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/vc4-kms-v3d-overlay.dtb
arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/vc4-kms-v3d-overlay.dts:8:39: fatal error: dt-bindings/clock/bcm2835.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/vc4-kms-v3d-overlay.dtb] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays] Error 2
make: *** [dtbs] Error 2
```

Know that I have successfully built zImage using:

```
$ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make zImage
```

Answer (score 0):

`vc4-kms-v3d-overlay.dtb` seems to be referring to the wrong `include` directory. The correct `include` directory is in `kernel/rpi/include/`, so you will need to do the appropriate change inside `vc4-kms-v3d-overlay.dtb`.